# Celery class methods as tasks

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

I've read [celery.contrib.methods](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.methods.html) and have looked at the questions I could find here on stackoverflow but I'm still left with the following question:

When using class methods as tasks with celery how are things attached to `self` handled?

**EXAMPLE**

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = []

    @task()
    def bar(self, val):
        self.x.append(val)

    @task()
    def other(self, val):
        self.bar.delay(val).get() #I realize this is stupid
        return ''.join(self.x)
```

I realize this is a very contrived example but I'm just trying to wrap my head around the idea of using classes with celery.

Is what I'm pointing at in my example possible and asynchronous? Or does it block when accessing `self.x`?

Any advice or insight on using classes with celery would be appreciated.